# Unable to resolve compile time error in circe custom decoder

Tags: scala, playframework, circe

I am trying to write a custom encoder and decoder in Circe for an Object like

```
case class User(id: Long, name: String)
```

So far I have

```
implicit val encodeUser: Encoder[User]= Encoder.instance{
  case User(id, name) => Json.obj(
    "id" -> Json.fromLong(id),
    "name" -> Json.fromString(name)
  )
}

object User{
  implicit val decodeUser: Decoder[User]= Decoder.instance(c =>
  for{
  id <- c.downField("id").as[Long]
  name <- c.downField("name").as[String]
  }yield User(id, name)
  )
}
```

but in the decoder i see compilation error that says expected HCursor[NotInferedA] but found HCursor[Any]. Not able to figure out whats happening here. I am new to Scala, Circe. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In Ammonite (Scala 2.12.4) and Circe (0.9.3) it works for me. What version of Scala and Circe do you use?

Comment: scala: 2.11.7 and circe: 0.9.1

Comment: And what are your imports? `HCursor` should not be a parametric class, something is definitely wrong here.

Comment: I did it in a different way and got that working. Thanks!